# Problem with AMD Prorender install on MAC Catalina Blender 2.81

Tags: python, radeon-prorender-render-engine

When I install AMD Prorender I get this message:

```
Installation error: Could not find the python3.7m executable at /Users/administrator/Library/Application Support/Blender/2.81/blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.*/python/bin/python3.7m
```

Prorender always ends with saying the addon was installed, but it is not listed in Blender.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error and it successfully installed. I had to rename my blender application from "Blender 2.81" to "blender". Apparently the installer is hard-coded to search for the folder or application named "blender".

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be that there is an extra file you need to download to get the add-on to work. I know for a fact that for LuxCore render there is a similar issue, and that was solved by another file that needed to be downloaded for it to work. Another trick that might work in case there is no other file that needs to be installed would be to install the add-on in Blender manually. You would need to do this by looking at the start up file location for Blender, and searching until you find the file for add-ons. (This can be easily done by looking at the file location info Blender gives you in the info section of an add-on.)

Answer (score 0):

right click on the installer and open package contents. first run the check exec file which will take you through the nine registration process on the AMD Prorender website then run the installer exec file which should go through the whole procedure including downloading the python file in question. I had this problem yesterday although Prorender was still showing up on the 2.80 install of Blender.

If you already have it working on a previous version then you can also copy the rpr folder from the previous install folder in ~/Library/Application Support/Blender and paste in the 2.81 folder. I did that first to see if it would install.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same issue today and resolved it by creating a new folder in the Applications folder named "Blender", placing the Blender app in the folder then re-installing AMD ProRender and selecting the Blender folder as the directory. ProRender is now showing up in plugins. Hope that helps!